# MySQL query to fetch list of data using logical operations

Tags: java, php, mysql

The following are the list of different kinds of books that customers read in a library. The values are stored with the power of 2 in a column called bookType.

[image: List of customer reading books]

I need to fetch list of books with the combinations of persons who read
`only Novel Or only Fairytale Or only BedTime Or both Novel + Fairytale` 
 from the database with logical operational query.

Fetch list for the following combinations :

- person who reads only novel(Stored in DB as 1)
- person who reads both novel and fairy tale(Stored in DB as 1+2 = 3)
- person who reads all the three i.e {novel + fairy tale + bed time} (stored in DB as 1+2+4 = 7)

> The count of these are stored in the database in a column called BookType(marked with red in fig.)

How can I fetch the above list using MySQL query

From the example, I need to fetch users like novel readers (1,3,5,7).

Comment: I would start by investigating enums and sets -- or even junction tables.  MySQL has much better ways  of storing this type of information.

Answer (score 1):

The heart of this question is conversion of decimal to binary and mysql has a function to do just - CONV(num , from_base , to_base ); 
In this case from_base would be 10 and to_base would be 2.
I would wrap this in a UDF
So given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select id,username
    -> from users
    -> where id < 8;
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | John     |
|  2 | Jane     |
|  3 | Ali      |
|  6 | Bruce    |
|  7 | Martha   |
+----+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+------+------------+
| id   | type       |
+------+------------+
|    1 | novel      |
|    2 | fairy Tale |
|    3 | bedtime    |
+------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This UDF

```
drop function if exists book_type;
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `book_type`(
    `indec` int
)
RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
begin
declare   tempstring varchar(100);
declare   outstring  varchar(100);
declare   book_types varchar(100);
declare   bin_position int;
declare   str_length int;
declare  checkit int;
set tempstring =  reverse(lpad(conv(indec,10,2),4,0));
set str_length = length(tempstring);
set checkit = 0;
set bin_position = 0;
set book_types = '';
looper: while   bin_position < str_length do
        set bin_position = bin_position + 1;
        set outstring = substr(tempstring,bin_position,1);


        if outstring = 1    then
            set book_types = concat(book_types,(select trim(type) from t where id = bin_position),','); 
        end if;
end while; 

set outstring = book_types;

return outstring;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Results in

```
+----+----------+---------------------------+
| id | username | book_type(id)             |
+----+----------+---------------------------+
|  1 | John     | novel,                    |
|  2 | Jane     | fairy Tale,               |
|  3 | Ali      | novel,fairy Tale,         |
|  6 | Bruce    | fairy Tale,bedtime,       |
|  7 | Martha   | novel,fairy Tale,bedtime, |
+----+----------+---------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the loop in the UDF to walk through the binary string and that the position of the 1's relate to the ids in the look up table;
I leave it to you to code for errors and tidy up.

Comment: From the example, I need to fetch segments like novel readers (1,3,7). Can you explain how this will help me?

Comment: You could use find_in_set('novel ',book_type(u.id)) in the where clause of your select;

Comment: @ruby did you see my latest comment?